# Is it possible to reduce video light flicker with Bender?

Tags: compositing-nodes, light, video

This is more of a compositor question. I have a video that I filmed (actually, it's stop-motion), but it has lots of light flicker (and I mean lots. Every frame is brighter or darker than the other). Is it possible to reduce this light flicker using Blender? I know there are other programs to do this with, like VitrualDub or AfterEffects, but I was wondering if I could use my favorite program (Blender, ;) ) to do it too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer: It is possible. Long answer: It's not something anybody would want to do, as there is no automated way to average luminance and gamma curves from frame to frame. You'd need to do it manually and set endless keyframes.

Comment: @cegaton I am pretty sure if you can do it manually then you can script it with Python, which then would be one click. Not posting an answer as I have no idea how to calculate values for filter/adjustments.

Comment: That would be a feature request for a new node.

Comment: Not necessarily a new node. Not everything has to be done with on node. I am looking for a node setup maybe, or like elmo said, a Python script. Any way to do it would be fine.

Comment: This is my photographer half speaking, but I would go back and re-capture the image sequence, taking more care to keep the lighting constant between frames. The result will look much better and might even be easier than trying to keyframe the brightness like others have suggested. What caused the variation in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could normalize the brightness and dark values then retarget them but the gama value would be almost impossible to determine of the image is being over exposed. Deflicker is non trivial and requires inter frame access which blenders nodes don't have.

Comment: I guess you're saying that I'd have to do it manually. I did find something to do with the normalize node, and it worked well, but it removed some color-data and made the contrast on my images strange.

Comment: Yes you can never really know where the mid point of the brightness should be hence a strangely contrasty picture I guess.